# Handoff not working from web to native app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, handoff

At one point, I had web-to-native and native-to-web Handoff working on iOS 8. I've upgraded all my devices to iOS 9 betas, and I just noticed that I can't get web-to-native-app Handoff working. I'm not sure if it's an iOS 9 problem though. If I'm browsing my site on Mac Safari, my iPhone shows the Safari icon, when it should be showing my native App icon.

To be clear, Handoff is working from my iPhone app to my Mac (Safari), and it's working from my Mac (Safari, contacts, messages, mail, etc) to my iPhone. It's also working as native-app-to-native-app across an iPhone and an iPad. All this tells me I have everything configured correctly: minimum hardware requirements, iCloud logins, and my apple-app-site-association file.

My apple-app-site-associations file is accessible at these locations:

- http://example.com/apple-app-site-association
- http://www.example.com/apple-app-site-association
- https://example.com/apple-app-site-association
- https://www.example.com/apple-app-site-association

Any ideas on what I could look into to see what's failing, and why I'm not seeing my native app icon on the lock screen when trying to hand off from browser to native app?

Comment: Same here - I've double and triple checked everything (including that apple-app-site-association is served with MIME type application/pkcs7-mime), but it doesn't work.

Native-to-web and native-to-native handoff works, and so do Universal links (applinks entries in the same apple-app-site-association file). Don't know what to try next.